# How to use solc-js with Jest?

Tags: javascript, testing, solc

I can't compile solidity code in my Jest files, but without Jest it works fine.

Here is a test file:

```
const fs = require("fs")
const solc = require("solc")

describe("test", () => {
  test("", () => {
    const input = {
      "test.sol": fs.readFileSync("test.sol", "utf8")
    }

    const output = solc.compile({ sources: input })

    const bin = "0x" + output.contracts["test.sol:Test"].bytecode
    const abi = output.contracts["test.sol:Test"].interface

    console.log({ bin })
    console.log({ abi })
  })
})
```

Here is an error: `TypeError: soljson.cwrap is not a function`

If removed from this code all Jest things (describe, test), it works fine.

Comment: have you tried to move the `compile` outside the `describe` and then use the `test` just to retrieve the value from the output field?

Comment: Yes. There is the same error.

Comment: what about moving the compile inside another module e include it inside the tests with require/import

Answer (score 3):

Per [this comment](https://github.com/ethereum/solc-js/issues/31#issuecomment-385127411) on solc-js issue #31, you can append this stanza to `package.json`.

```
"jest": {
  "testEnvironment": "node"
}
```

(which I guess tells jest to run in node, which will bring in the things that solc needs).